# Can I tell an undefined action argument from a null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a POST action that receives some specific model from some form. If one of the model properties is not defined in the form and I try to access it, I will get a null (assuming the field was nullable). On the other hand, if I were to include the property in the form, but put an empty value there, I would still get a null. Is there any way for me to tell those two states apart?

I mean, functions such as `UpdateModel` ignore undefined properties, but respect defined nulls. This suggests that it should be possible to tell one from another, but how to do that?

Comment: Just a guess, but would an empty field still show up in the `Request.QueryString`? I can't test it at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: @Flater Sounds plausible. Gotta test it.

Comment: This is why we use ViewModels to update our data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my original problem differently so I no longer needed the functionality described above, but today for one reason or another I needed to check if `QueryString` contains a key (and preferably in a case insensitive way). Since I wasn't able find such method in `QueryString` (maybe it has some obscure name or I didn't just search enough), I wrote an extension:

```
public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions
{
    public static bool HasKey(this System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection, string keyToFind, bool caseSensitive = true)
    {
        foreach (var key in collection.Keys)
        {
            if ((!caseSensitive && key.ToString().ToLower() == keyToFind.ToLower()) || (key.ToString() == keyToFind && caseSensitive))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Incidentally this should allow checking if action argument was defined (like Flater suggested). For example:

```
bool someKeyIsDefined = Request.QueryString.HasKey("SomeKey", false);
```

---

Apparently this can be also done using the `AllKeys` property which returns the list of keys as good old string array and you can process it using linq.